# **kwargs and default arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword-argument

```
class Klass:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.func(variable=True, **kwargs)

  def func(self, variable=True, **kwargs):
    print(variable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  Klass(variable=False)
```

I was wondering why I am getting `TypeError: func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'variable'`.

I am thinking it should print `False` because I override the default value of `variable` to `False` and pass `kwargs` along the way.

Comment: Parameters with default value should be trailing arguments.. change the order..

Comment: @PriyankMehta Not for Python 2.7.

Comment: You can do `kwargs['variable'] = True`

Comment: @Elazar: That would ignore any caller provided `variable` and forcibly replace it with the value `True`. [As I mention in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940623/364696) `kwargs.setdefault('variable', True)` would keep the caller's value, if provided, and if not provided, create the key and set the value to `True`.

Comment: @PriyankMehta / @metatoaster: Not in Python 3 either. You always put defaulted arguments before `**kwargs`; it's a `SyntaxError` for `**kwargs` to appear anywhere but as the final argument.

Comment: Yup right problem is mixing positional and keyword arguments

Comment: @PriyankMehta: No... There are no uses of positional arguments anywhere in the OP's code (unless you count `self`, which is both positional and implicitly passed).

Comment: @ShadowRanger you are right, I read the question wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't pass the same argument twice, and `variable=True, **kwargs` does exactly that when `kwargs` contains a key for `variable`; in this case, you made the call effectively `self.func(variable=True, variable=False)` which is clearly wrong. Assuming you can't receive `variable` as a separate argument, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self, variable=True, **kwargs):
    self.func(variable, **kwargs)

# On Python 3, you can easily keep variable keyword-only with:
def __init__(self, *, variable=True, **kwargs):
    self.func(variable, **kwargs)

# while the Python 2 equivalent for keyword-only args is rather nastier:
def __init__(self, *positional_forbidden, variable=True, **kwargs):
    if positional_forbidden:
        raise TypeError("__init__ takes 1 positional argument but {} were given".format(len(positional_forbidden)+1))
    self.func(variable, **kwargs)
```

then the other approach is to set the default in the `kwargs` `dict` itself:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('variable', True)  # Sets variable to True only if not passed by caller
    self.func(**kwargs)
```

In Python 3.5, with [PEP 448's additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you could one-line this safely as:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.func(**{'variable': True, **kwargs})
```

because repeated keys are legal when creating a new `dict` (only the last occurrence of a key is kept), so you can create a brand new `dict` with unique mappings, then immediately unpack it.

Comment: Wondering why does Python think I am passing the same argument twice instead of overriding the default value of `variable`?

Comment: @ZizhengWu Because you _are_ passing the same argument twice. Once with `variable=True`, and once with the `**{'variable': False}`.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that (assuming the OP doesn't care about Python 2) you can do `def __init__(self, *, variable=True, **kwargs):`. That gives you the advantages of the first version (explicitly visible in the signature, not forced to go through kwargs) without the possible disadvantage. (Of course if being able to pass it positionally is something you _want_, rather than something you _want to avoid_, it's not a disadvantage at all, and your first version is already perfect.)

Comment: @ZizhengWu: Because `**kwargs` is defined to mean "act as if all the key/value pairs in the dictionary were passed one-by-one as keyword arguments". Function calls reject duplicated arguments precisely because of the confusion involved in accidentally passing duplicate arguments; normally this is because someone passes an argument positionally and by keyword, but passing twice by keyword is equally wrong.

Comment: Like I said, `dict` literals have different rules for duplicate handling, so in Python 3.5 it's easy to opt in to a "duplicate friendly" approach, but function calls are stricter, because duplicate args are *usually* an error.

Comment: @abarnert your comment is really useful! Please consider to add it to the answer / proposed solution

Comment: @RedSparrow: The OP's question is specifically tagged for Python 2, which is why I omitted that possibility. I'm fine leaving it as an upvoted comment.

Comment: @RedSparrow: With Python 2 dead, I decided to edit the top solution to show a Python 3 (and a keyword-only Python 2) solution that keep the semantics unchanged (all arguments must be passed by keyword). For library authors, it's definitely a problem if users can accidentally rely on an argument being either positional or keyword in Python 2, which becomes keyword only in Python 3, so documenting how to do it "the right way" in both versions is useful. In hindsight, should have done so from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an object of class `Klass`,

```
Klass(variable=False)
```

the `variable` is parsed as an keyword argument (`kwargs`), which is a `dict` anyway. So inside the `__init__` method, you can find the `kwargs` being like

```
{'variable': False'}
```

And in

```
self.func(variable=True, **kwargs)
```

the double asterisk implies to parse everything in a `dict` as keyword arguments. Technically this line is equal to

```
self.func(variable=True, **{'variable': False'})
```

and equal to

```
self.func(variable=True, variable=False)
```

And that's why you got a `TypeError`.

Here's is probably what you are looking for:

```
class Klass:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.func(**kwargs)

  def func(self, variable=True, **kwargs):
    print(variable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Klass(variable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're putting to variable arguments, so python doesn't know which is right, so it raises an error

Clearer example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f(a=4,a=5)
    def f(self,a):
        return a

SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Klass:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.func(**kwargs)

  def func(self, variable=True, **kwargs):
    print(variable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  Klass(variable=False)
```

This should work. You are setting a default value 'True' and passing a parameter 'False' to one keyword 'variable'.